# Find all occurrences and add them together

Tags: bash, shell-script, csv

I have a file like this:

```
user1, 10
user2, 5
user2, 6
user1, 15
user3, 23
user1, 15
```

I'd like to have totals by column 1 (user1, user2, user3), and make it look like this:

```
user1, 40
user2, 11
user3, 23
```

What would be the best way forward? A `while` loop on the first column and sum up the 2nd column as long as it's the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One-line awk:

```
$ awk -F, '{a[$1] += $2} END { for (x in a) printf "%s, %s\n", x, a[x] }' < data
user1, 40
user2, 11
user3, 23
```

That's rather straightforward, the field separator is set to the comma with `-F,` (this, and the comma in the output are about the only changes needed from the duplicate). `$1` and `$2` are the first and second fields, and since awk has associative arrays, collecting the sums is simple. You may need to `sort` the output afterward if that matters.

---

Sure, we could do this purely in Bash/ksh/zsh too, since it also supports associative arrays, but it would be uglier, slower and more prone to accidents with funny values. And only useful on a system that for some reason has a big shell, but no awk. (see edit history if you really want that...)

Comment: Both are valid `bash` code, but as you say, the second one is not the right way to process text in shells.

Comment: Note that the order will not be deterministic.